# How can I convert a UTF8 string to a codepage in PHP?

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a string which is in UTF-8 and have codepages (numbers). How can I convert a UTF-8 string to a codepage?

Comment: Did you try utf8_decode?

Comment: What do you mean in conversion? Get associated decimal value of utf8 character?

Comment: `iconv("UTF8", "CODEPAGE", $string)` ?

Comment: @PLB that is my guess as well

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "äöå"; //File is saved as UTF-8
$codepage = unpack("N*",mb_convert_encoding( $string, "UTF-32BE", "UTF-8" ));

var_dump( $codepage );

//array(3) { [1]=> int(228) [2]=> int(246) [3]=> int(229) }
```

Comment: allright.... I tried this "iconv ('UTF-8', '1252', $str)" at it said: "Wrong charset, conversion from `UTF-8' to `1252' is not allowed"

Comment: @JohnSmith not sure why you would do that. I use `mb_convert_encoding` with `UTF-8` -> `UTF-32BE`. It doesn't make sense to convert to `1252` as it only has 251 characters.

Answer (score 1):

ok, it looks I found:

```
$out = iconv("UTF-8", 'Windows-1252//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $out);
```

a Windows- prefix was needed. Also good to translit and ignore